# Is there any way to modify a problem with change in variables in opta planner and run it in parallel with the original one

Tags: java, optaplanner, timefold

For instance if we have a problem statement to schedule number of rooms to a group of people for a specific time(in minutes) for a given length of day(in hours).

I'm setting the configuration so as to say that the perfect job would result in 0 hard score. Let's say due to some complications the scheduler could not find a perfect solution with 0 hard score, is it possible for me to run a parallel scheduling job with some change in variables i.e. increasing the length of the day by 1 hour or reducing the time 1 group can have the room for or increasing the number of rooms.

Is it possible to run parallel scheduling jobs in case the original job cannot provide a solution with 0 hard score?

Thanks.

Comment: If you can run the solver once, what prevents you running it a second time? If you can run it in one thread, what prevents you from running two threads? I probably do not understand the question well enough.

Comment: @LukášPetrovický I want to provide end user with recommendations to tweak some variables so that the planner can give them acceptable results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no functionality for this in OptaPlanner or [Timefold](https://timefold.ai/blog/2023/optaplanner-fork/) (yet).

That said, nothing prevents you from making the change to the data set and running the solver again. You can use [SolverManager](https://timefold.ai/docs/timefold-solver/latest/configuration/configuration.html#solverManager) to execute multiple solvers at the same time. It is then up to you how you present the results to the user.